# I need a regEx to match general URLs

Tags: regex, url, string-matching

I need to test for general URLs using any protocol (http, https, shttp, ftp, svn, mysql and things I don't know about).

My first pass is this:

```
\w+://(\w+\.)+[\w+](/[\w]+)(\?[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?
```

([PCRE](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) and [.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx) so nothing to fancy)

Comment: That expression matches too much (_ isn't allowed in domain names, IIRC, URL can stop after domain name) and not enough (one can find ~ and any %hh character in the path).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [RFC2396](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2396.html):

```
^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
```

Comment: OK so the windows //server/dir/file thing IS a URL? kind of make the file:////server/dir/file in FF/IE look even more bazaar

Comment: this is a pretty dangerous regex. It actually captures all the text before and after the url as well. It doesn't work for my purposes. I'd definitely check on this before using it.

Answer (score 2):

adding that RegEx as a wiki answer:

```
[\w+-]+://([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)+[[a-zA-Z0-9]+](/[%\w]+)(\?[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?
```

option 2 (Re CMS)

```
^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
```

But that's to lax for anything sane so trimmed to make it more restrictive and to differentiate off other things.

```
proto      ://  name      : pass      @  server    :port      /path     ? args
^([^:/?#]+)://(([^/?#@:]+(:[^/?#@:]+)?@)?[^/?#@:]+(:[0-9]+)?)(/[^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?
```

Comment: Another possibility is 'svn+ssh://'. I don't think \w would match '+'.

Answer (score 1):

I came at this from a slightly different direction. I wanted to emulate gchats ability to match `something.co.uk` and linkify it. So I went with a regex that looks for a `.` without either a following period or a space on either side and then grabs everything around it until it hits whitespace. It does match a period at the end of a URI but I'm taking that off later. So this could be an option if you would prefer false positives over missing some potentials

```
url_re = re.compile(r"""
           [^\s]             # not whitespace
           [a-zA-Z0-9:/\-]+  # the protocol and domain name
           \.(?!\.)          # A literal '.' not followed by another
           [\w\-\./\?=&%~#]+ # country and path components
           [^\s]             # not whitespace""", re.VERBOSE) 

url_re.findall('http://thereisnothing.com/a/path adn some text www.google.com/?=query#%20 https://somewhere.com other-countries.co.nz. ellipsis... is also a great place to buy. But try text-hello.com ftp://something.com')

['http://thereisnothing.com/a/path',
 'www.google.com/?=query#%20',
 'https://somewhere.com',
 'other-countries.co.nz.',
 'text-hello.com',
 'ftp://something.com']
```